# How do I stop, tune and restart a MariaDB Galera cluster?

Tags: mariadb, galera

So I have 4 nodes running on some fast but smallist (ram wise) vps machines. This is very cool but they are using 100% of the memory available. I need to turn off performance schema and possibly lower some other settings to get this running at or near 7-800 mbs.

Before I try to do service mysqld stop, I thought I better ask.

Comment: You shouldn't use an even number of nodes if possible since it is easier to get into no quorum situation.

Comment: Okay thanks I now have it at 5 nodes and will grow in odds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will chime in the answer here now that I have done this. So after tuning the mysqld settings I did a plain old service mysql restart and it worked perfectly. As long as you have **EDIT please see above, grow in odds with at least 3 running** running it does not seem to care at a restart.

Comment: i had to reinstall whole mariadb from root after tryign everyitng